# What is the maximum size of data we can send through GCM in Android

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement GCM in Android. IS it allows any length of text to send through GCM Server or Is there any limit to send Push notification ?

Any solutions are appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

[Refer this link](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html),It will send maximum 4kb data

Comment: **@Boopathi!** Thanking you for your solution. If i want to send a message like big passage with more than 100 lines of code to the Android mobile. Then is there any possibility from 3rd party server  to Android mobile

Comment: yes 3rd party will provide how much you have to send to any device

Comment: Yha, from 3rd party server you can send any length of text but through GCM it allows only 4kb at a time right? So, how its possible i'm confusing in this. So, can u please explain this?

Comment: GCM only allows a message less than 4Kb, so if you wan to push a big size message you can push a web link to your user,  and you can then dispose the web link in your app.